# Assembly final exam tomorrow Need some exercise

Tags: assembly, irvine32

I have an Assembly final tomorrow.
Any one have some ideas for a programming exercise?

i need muls, divs, loops and such..

all X86 instructions, I will be cheating a bit by using the irvine32 lib

Im looking for beginner-intermediate level exercises achievable in 1-3 hrs

Please something within reason, i will post my final answer for critique.

Comment: About what level of exercise are you looking for? There's a big difference between, say, generating Collatz sequences and writing a miniature kernel.

Comment: its x86 and im looking for something 1-3hrs

Comment: Just wanted to comment and wish you "good luck", coz Assembly looks like encrypted data to me =)

Comment: @BeemerGuy: thanks, its pretty simple in some sense.. I just completed a "towers of hanoi" solver with playback

Comment: @madmaze: That doesn't tell us much about your competence level, though. I know people who could knock out the core of a minikernel in an hour or two, and I know people who would struggle to produce a sequence of numbers in the same timeframe. Can you give us an example of the sorts of exercises you expect?

Comment: Im looking for more advanced things that Fibonacci or calculators(with factorial and things)

Comment: I am by no means an expert in ASM, hence im taking a course in it. Im looking for something probably more on a beginner level

Comment: @BeemerGuy: actually, i think ill write an encryption program for strings, maybe more.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the first million primes with a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

A lot of the early problems in [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems) would also be good candidates.  Plus if you register you can test your solutions there.

Comment: Thanks, Im actually already signed up there.. and well totally forgot about it.

Comment: I did problem 5, which is finding the first number evenly divisible by 1-20.. runs a hellova lot faster in asm then in python haha

Comment: It's too bad that most of the comment threads are closed on those early problems.  I solved a bunch of them with shell scripts and you did that one in assembly, which I bet would be unique.